# Render result colours not matching the saved image/video colours

Tags: rendering, color-management

With blender 2.92 I have rendered an image and a video that came out perfectly in the Render Result window but when I save it, blender apply some kind of light filmic filter to it.

I have tried a lot of different combinations in the render menu and output menu without any result. The rendering engines do not change anything as well.
I have tried to save with all file format as well.

Do you know how save a rendered image/video as same as in the render result window?

---

Here the 2 pictures.

The first in the render result window (screenshot) with good colours.

The second the output saved in any format (Tiff,jpg...) colours are different. More lavish...

[image: Render result colours ok]

[image: Colours after saving in any format]

Comment: in the Properties panel > Render > Color Management, what is your View Transform setting? Is it Standard or Filmic?

Comment: moonboots wants to say: set it to standard ;) he is just too shy to say it directly :D

Comment: It is already set to standard I am afraid...

Comment: Maybe attaching a screenshot to show the render result and the saved image to see how different it actually looks could help. Or upload your file here https://blend-exchange.com to check the settings and try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: It is specially visible with light coloured pictures.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem?

Comment: This happens with the video editor as well. So every time we save a rendering the colour goes away. So If we render a scene then save it then use the VSE to make a montage the result will be completely out of colours for good. Double washed away :-)